# how to get ip address from onion url using python

Tags: torsocks, python

I am trying to get ip address from darknet onion url.

import subprocess 
import ipaddress 
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('5.0.0.0/24'): 
subprocess.call(["tor-resolve", "-x", ip])

I am not getting correct thing, this is error also.
who is there for helping me?

Comment: This will be helpful also?
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150
', 'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150
'}
response = session.get("https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/
")

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do because it doesn't seen to make any sense. You should never get an IP address from an onion service unless the person who set it up did a REALLY bad job. Onion services are anonymous just like the users that use them.

Comment: Thanks @JSEvans, but can't "tor-resolve -x onion-url" will not working for me?

Comment: how can get contents of onion url using python?

Comment: Here's the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/tor-resolve.  This tool is like nslookup but instead of using a local DNS server, it is doing the lookup over tor. If you do nslookup google.com, you will see the information that your DNS provider has and it will resolve the IP address.  tor-resolve is similar but it works via tor. So if you do tor-resolve google.com, you should get the IP address but your DNS provider won't know that you're doing it because it is via Tor.  If you run in against an onion service, it *should not* work because there is nothing to resolve.

Comment: i have legit onion url list. how should i resolve ip addresss from onion url over tor using python? can you test in your end and show me your script? Thank you very much

Comment: "how should i resolve ip addresss from onion url over tor" the answer is that you don't. This isn't something that Tor allows.
---
"how can get contents of onion url using python?". I don't know Python well enough but I would find a function like curl. `torsocks curl onionabcxyz.onion` will give you the contents of the onion site. It will not give you the IP address. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python has some options to do that. Just run it inside of torsocks or with a socks5 proxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105514/discussion-between-jincowboy-and-jsevans).

Comment: can you let me know your skype id?

Comment: I would rather not. If you want to chat, please join the Tor IRC channel (https://www.torproject.org/contact/) or the Tor-Talk mailing list (https://lists.torproject.org/). The Tor developers are there and can give better programming advice than I can.